# List Returning 0 after Adding values through a for loop - c#

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

After this method my List count return 0 while it shouldn't. All the debugs are correct neither of them is null or something. I am using Unity.
Does anyone know where is the problem?

```
List<Coordinates> FillCoordinates()
{
    List<Coordinates> coordinatesList = new List<Coordinates>();
    Debug.Log(minLenght);
    Debug.Log(maxLenght);
    Debug.Log(heights.Count);
    for (int i = minLenght; i > maxLenght; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < heights.Count; j++)
        {
            coordinatesList.Add(new Coordinates(i, heights[j]));
        }
    }

    return coordinatesList;
}
```

Coordinates class:

```
public class Coordinates
{
    public int lenght;
    public float height;

    public Coordinates(int lenght_, float height_)
    {
        lenght = lenght_;
        height = height_;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = minLenght; i **<** maxLenght; i++)`

Comment: `Lenght` is a typo. Should be `Length`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing this never executes, change i < maxLenght

```
    for (int i = minLenght; i > maxLenght; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < heights.Count; j++)
        {
            coordinatesList.Add(new Coordinates(i, heights[j]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: i dont want him to stop before max lenght i want im to stop when i is equal to max lenght. Do you see any reason for it not to execute?

Comment: The for loop never executes because i is equal to minLenght which is not greater than maxLenght. You need to change the ">" to "<" which will accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 3):

@obl is right, this will not execute:

```
for (int i = minLenght; i > maxLenght; i++)
```

The for-loop statement reads:
*"Start with `i` at `minLength`, and while `i` is greater than `maxLength`, run the loop and then increment `i`."*

As i isn't greater than maxLength, the loop will never run.

Change it to this:

```
for (int i = minLenght; i < maxLenght; i++)
```

*"Start with `i` at `minLength`, and while `i` is less than `maxLength`, run the loop and then increment `i`."*

It will now run from `minLength` all the way up to `maxLength-1`.

You are right that this won't run the loop one final time when `i` is equal to `maxLength`. To fix that (if it's really what you want), simply adjust it like this:

```
for (int i = minLenght; i <= maxLenght; i++)
```

*"Start with `i` at `minLength`, and while `i` is less than or equal to `maxLength`, run the loop and then increment `i`."*

Comment: true i dont know why but i was thiking the oposite thank you